# What protocol of AllCast use for casting tvOS ?

Tags: objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to implement an app like Allcast which can use to scan nearby  (Apple TV) and pass image,audio,video through apple tv to show them.
But i cant figure it out. What protocol AllCast use ? 
I tried AirPlay but it can't custom UI like Allcast (Scan device, IP, imagepreview),...

[image]

Allcast AppleStore: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/allcast-cast-photos-music/id943763227?mt=8

Comment: I think it belong to "ios" tag too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a sdk for these stuffs.
ConnectSDK is greate. 
https://github.com/ConnectSDK